# WCF client process crashes with StackOverflow after many calls to WCF server

Tags: c#, wcf, crash, stack-overflow

I have a WCF server which is working with database. It is working in single instance and multiple threads mode. Almost every method represents a simple operation to database. On the client side there are many WCF-channels (proxies) which are created at the same time (of course I have various 'lock's when creating a new channel) in multiple threads and as the result I have many concurrent connections (in one client process) to one service.

After some quantity of these calls to the server, my client process crashes. It is not an unhandled exception, the application just crashes and exits. The moment of the crash is not determined. With the help of 'procdump.exe' I have found that it is crashed with StackOverflow after a lot of AccessDenied.

I guess the problem is in WCF messaging queue on the client process side but I cannot solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you wait for a response from request #1 before sending request #2, or is everything running independently on its own thread? If you're not waiting, that might be your problem. You've got table and row locks stacking up until the client finally blows.

Comment: Everything is running independently on its own thread but WCF server also is running in concurrencymode=multiple.

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to wait for a response on the client before making the next request just to see what happens. I'd leave the host as it is. I've had some experience load testing a big WCF service - I was able to get it to upload 150 files a second asychronously with a multi-threaded app. But with a database, I think I'd either limited the number of threads or make each wait before spinning out a nother.

Comment: I've tested WCF server with a single thread configuration. The result is the same. I've noticed one strange moment: process crashes not on the all servers and it does not crash in debug mode.

Comment: Sergey - I don't know what else to suggest. Good luck to you.